# Flash can't open script because of missing Font

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, fonts

I just downloaded an open source flash project but the second I open it function names and variables are displayed like this: "[][][][]" because my system seems to be missing the font it was created in. The font appears to be "Courier New TUR" which is probably delivered whith a Turkish windows license or something. I've been trying to find this font without succeeding for hours.

Does anyone know any solution for my problem?

Comment: Does Flash not ask you if you want to replace the missing font with a new one?

Comment: Try changing your pc or mac language to turkish? OR try changing the settings in the IDE to Arial which should cover turkish.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in another editor? Say notepad++?

Comment: The whole code is inside a FLA file. Wouldn't this just display gibberish in another editor?

Comment: I would wager that it would be gibberish, yes. It isn't like opening a .as file.